# AngularJS Material UI where dialog comes out of the clicked element

Tags: css, angularjs

Just trying to figure out how AngularJS does this effect with its dialogs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

If you notice the dialog pops out from the button bounds and falls back into it.

How can I achieve this effect with css/javascript in react?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Developer Console to inspect, the element shows that it uses transition CSS:

```
md-dialog.md-transition-in {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1);
    transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
    transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
}
```